# How would I implement this New Type of NN

Tags: ai-design, training, deep-neural-networks

**CIO NN**

CIO NN stands for **C**ontroller **I**nput **O**utput **N**erual **N**etwork

note due to a typo the "**nearon**" means "**neron**"

For this we have to redefine the Nearon

- 2 Inputs
- 2 Outputs
- 4 Weights (each input and output have their own weights)
- Internal Memory Cell (any byte or bit or block size with variable size)
- Activation Function (Defines what weights and what inputs activate this Nearon)
- Memory Storage Function (Defines what and when this cell should store said memory or memory stream)
- Memory Transpose Function (Once activated any stored memory that the activation function can trigger will be played/pushed into the Nerual Network)
- Forget Function (Defines when and/or how and/or why these memories can be destroyed/removed based on Activation function with Memory states and any input stateses itself)

How would I implement this in the form of Code?
please take note of the spec. (this is non profit/GNU v3)

**This would look something like these:**
[image: Basic CIO Nearon]

These would be arranges like this:
[image]

Which we can build it into this:
[image]

it can be trained like this:

- do normal NN training from the inputs to the input outputs like a hidden layer NN

then trained to be controlled like this:

- then set the known NN dataset (inputs) to be corrected to actual or correct values via the CI (Controller Input) which will be outputed on the "Input + Controller Input" Output

by training like this:

- you have a normal NN with hidden layers which can be trainned (this can be done with CNNs) with backpropergation, and a cost function (use least amount of nerons) etc
- now you can allow the CIO NN to retrain / teach itself with supervised or unsupervised learning.
- you can combine the "Input Output" and the "Input + Controller Input" Output with another NN which can then connect with this NN in a similiar way that a Neron connects to a Neron